# What is the best way to update entire MySQL table with data coming from another table

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-update

I am building a new functionality and have an idea how to do it, however there might be a better way out there, which I have not though of. So any 'crazy' ideas are welcomed.

This is the case:

I have a products table that contains 9 different types of products. Let's call it `tbl_all_products`. This table contain about 100K records and is regularly being updated - either by the users (they can add/remove products) or by automated scripts (like delete outdated ones). So understandably, there will be holes in the table ids and a lot of variations in the product types order.

Now what I want to do is to get a new cron in place which will extract products from `tbl_all_products` only `WHERE prod_id = '1'`, query might be something like:

```
    $sql_product = "SELECT id,name,date,user_id 
                    FROM tbl_all_products
                    WHERE type = '1';
```

Then I want to update those 4 columns for all matching products in a new table, let's call it `tbl_type1`.

I am planning to to record the count of selected products with `type=1` and then update those with a loop in `tbl_type1 WHERE id=$count_id`. 
One question leaves for me to think about if I choose this approach and it is what to do with the excessive rows in `tbl_type1` when there are less products found in the original table.

But I would like to get some other opinions if there is a better and more importantly, a faster way to do it.

Any suggestions or thoughts?

Comment: `INSERT INTO <newTable> (SELECT * FROM <oldTable>)`

Comment: But what is your problem with gaps in the id values? If that's your PK, then it shouldn't matter if there are gaps or not, just as long as they are unique

Comment: @Mark Baker, this approach will only add up rows in the new table and I want to replace any previous values there with new ones, might be the same or different...the idea is to have a list with consecutive id only for product only for products `WHERE type=1`. What I will do with the new table is to get 1 row from there and display the data on a page where row_id = page_id. Ultimate goal is to have a unique product type1 on each different page.

Comment: You realise that an `INSERT` statement also allows `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`? - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html

Comment: But you really have a bee in your bonnet about consecutive ids..... this really shouldn't matter to you at all unless you're misusing those id values and assigning some special meaning to them

Comment: then I might just `TRUNCATE` the new table before each `INSERT` operation. This should do it.

Comment: As for using the id as page number.... use ORDER BY ID LIMIT x,1 instead (where x is the page number -1), then you don't need to worry about consecutive id values

Comment: This should work in the situation you have in mind but as usual there is more in the background than I am sharing...for keeping the question simple. I want to get all products type1 and do an `ORDER BY RAND()`. Then insert them in the new table. So every time the scrip executes, I will have a different product displayed on page1, page2, etc. And I am doing the `ORDER by RAND()` separately in another table for two reasons 1.Avoid having different product every time the page loads and 2.improve page load speed :) But a valuable suggestion indeed!